# Unable to split string stored in a variable containing $ as the delimiter

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to split this string and store substrings in separate variables as follows:

```
temp="one$two$three$fourfive"
IFS="$" read var1 var2 var3 var4 <<< "$temp"
```

When I echo var1 I get "one" but when I echo var2 there is no output.
It works when I add a '\' before every $ sign but when I try to do it programmatically:

```
echo "$temp" | sed 's/$/\\$/g'

Output: one\$
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Or simply create an array of the split values, e.g. `IFS=$'$\n'; array=( $(echo $tmp) )`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, test with `tmp='-n$/*'`.

Comment: Where does `tmp='-n$/*'` come from? I thought the question was `temp="one$two$three$fourfive"`?

Comment: Barath R, note that the code in the question (even with the quoting and `read` usage fixes given in the solution by Inian) doesn't work for all possible values of `$temp`.  In particular, it fails of the string contains newline characters.  Test with `temp=$'a\nb$c$d$e'`.  See [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/918886/4154375) for many solutions to the general problem.  Unfortunately, many of the solutions don't work in all circumstances.  The solution by gniourf_gniourf is good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with the original string `temp` where with double quotes, your rest of the strings `two`, `three` and `fourfive` are interpreted as shell variables.

Using single quotes on the `temp` string would let the variables to *not* to be expanded to an empty string.

```
temp='one$two$three$fourfive'
```

Also recommend using `read` with `-r` flag to not let not backslashes mangle your string

```
IFS='$' read -r var1 var2 var3 var4 <<< "$temp"
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't with reading them, it's when you assigned to `temp` in the first place. Variables are expanded inside double quotes, so it tries to use the values of `$two`, `$three`, etc. Since these variables don't exist, you just did:

```
temp="one"
```

You would have noticed this if you simply did:

```
echo "$temp"
```

You need to use single quotes instead of double quotes, so variables won't be expanded.

```
temp='one$two$three$fourfive'
IFS="$" read var1 var2 var3 var4 <<< "$temp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `read` isn't necessary, a `bash` array would be better than separate variables:

```
temp='one$two$three$fourfive'
var=(${temp//$/ })
printf '%s\n' ${var[@]}
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
fourfive
```

Comment: Test with `temp='a b$/*'`.

Comment: @pjh, Thanks, but not unless the OP specifies that the data may [contain `*`s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_case).  Most *nix tools are designed with the presumption that the input data is normal, or at least pre-cleaned.  If the data can't be cleaned, a language with [counted strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Length-prefixed) would be a win for safety.